# Serverless architecture on GCP and data residency concern

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging

In general any cloud service provider, GCP in this context, is it not relevant and mandatory for Google to specifically allow consumers to choose data residency and data processing region option for all services? Else serverless option will have serious adoption issue. Please clarify.

Comment: I believe they have encrypted cache. Why don't you ask directly to their sales team?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. If your question is "Can I specify where my data and services are located?". The answer is yes for most services. Some services are only available in certain regions either because they are brand new or do not require global deployment. Please edit your question and specify a question that does not require opinions and applies to software development/programming problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud have two types of the products available: that have specified location and available globally.

You can deploy resources in specific location, multi-regional for:

1. Compute: Compute Engine, App Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, Cloud Functions
2. Storage & Databases: Cloud Storage, Bigtable, Spanner, Cloud SQL, Firestore, Memorystore, Persistent Disk...
3. BigData & Machine learning: BigQuery, Composer, Dataflow, Dataproc, AI training,
4. Networking: VPC, Cloud Load Balancing,
5. Developer Tools...

Following products are available only globally: Networking, Big Data Pub/Sub, Machine Learning like vision API, Management Tools, Developer Tools, IAM.

For detailed list please check [Google Cloud Locations Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?region=americas#region)

Even if the product is available globally, for example [PubSub: it is possible to specify where messages are stored](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics#messagestoragepolicy).

If the data in transit are the concern, you have to be aware that [Google Cloud Platform uses data encryption at Rest](https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/). It consists on several layers of encryption to protect customer data.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the documentation. My concern is as below. When the globally available services, by compliance needs, the data needs to be stored in the region where the data originates. Unfortunately, there is no specific mention that the data will not be moved out of region. By architecture, it is implicit derivation that the service stores the data where the latency is low. This may not be sufficient to convince the customer.

Comment: Contd ...  For ex. PubSub, the messages get persisted (when not delivered yet) in the region (derivation is that region near to the place of origination as latency is lowest, but no guarantee). This is where customers who are hellbent on the data residency compliance will not opt for PubSub, but look at the alternative such as Managed Kafka. The similar argument applies to other global services.

Comment: For the PubSub storage you can set: [MessageStoragePolicy to specify region when data are stored](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics#messagestoragepolicy).

Comment: Thank you. I shall explore this further.

Comment: Hi @RaghavendraPrakash can you accept my answer if it responds your question? For better visibility for another SO users.